# Mysql , how to join 2 result , ideas are welcome

Tags: mysql

The thing is that i have 3 queries that can't be  done together because  they use a `WHERE` clause from different columns.

**result query 1**

```
+----+----------+
| id |    1D    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | colorado |
|  2 | azul     |
+----+----------+
```

**result query 2**

```
+----+------+
| id |  2D  |
+----+------+
|  1 | int  |
|  2 | ext  |
+----+------+
```

what I want to do, is joining the two results by the id:

```
+----+----------+------+
| id |    1D    |  2D  |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | colorado | int  |
|  2 | azul     | ext  |
+----+----------+------+
```

I thought to use UNION , but the columns are different; temporary table could be or an array in mysql .

what I can do is to join them in one array in php but if someone have a better idea to do it in mysql it will be a great help.

Comment: What you are asking is standard SQL. What you need to supply here is the table definitions and an example of the other SQL used to generate the first and second query.  More than likely you simply need to amalgamate the 2 queries, by specifying the additional table and fields to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SQL JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.`1d`, t2.`2d`
FROM (query1) AS t1
JOIN (query2) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```